# How to send http request with PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, http, https, pyqt

I want to send http GET request using PyQt.

Despite my researches, I haven't found any examples of that simple manipulation in python.

I've ended up with some code (that I have modified according to the hints given by Bakuriu in the comments), but it doesn't work. Let's say I want to make a get request to facebook webpage, and print the answer, which should be the HTML content of the page.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtNetwork, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys
from functools import partial

def printContent():
    answerAsText = QString(replyObject.readAll())
    print answerAsText 

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

url = QtCore.QUrl("http://www.facebook.com")
request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest()
request.setUrl(url)
manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()

replyObject = manager.get(request)
replyObject.finished.connect(printContent)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This doesn't raise any error, it just doesn't print anything. 
I don't know where the problem is : 
Is my request wrong ? 
Or is it the way I handle the reply object afterwards ?

Why doesn't it work ? Could somebody please show me a functioning code ?

Comment: `QNetworkReply` is a `QIODevice` so it provides the methods [`readData` and `readLineData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#protected-functions).

Comment: Yeah, I searched in that direction already. But I don't understand how it works. All the functions (read, readAll, readData, readLine) returns QByteArrays, and I don't know what to do with them. 
+ readData takes an int argument which meaning I don't get. Could you please be a bit more specific about how to handle this object

Comment: Well a `QByteArray` is just text. If you want it as text you can just do `text = QString(data)`.

Comment: I just edited the code in my question to make a more generic case. Let's say I want the make a GET request to "http://facebook.com". It should give me the HTML content of facebook welcome page. 
This code doesn't work, the readAll method seems to give an empty object. What is the problem there ?

Comment: The problem might be that the request is asynchronous. So you have to wait for the `finished()` signal on the request, and only read the data when you receive it. So do something like: `bytArrayAnswer.finished.connect(my_callback)` and inside `my_callback` you use `readAll` to obtain the text.

Comment: Also you should check using the `attribute` method if you received an OK response (status `200`) or something else...

Answer (score 5):

We need to create a `QApplication` or `QtCoreApplication`, because we are using the signal and slot mechanism. Notice also that the response has to be decoded from a `QByteArray`.

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork
import sys
      
      
class Example:
  
    def __init__(self):    
        
        self.doRequest()
        
        
    def doRequest(self):   
    
        url = "http://webcode.me"
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        
        self.nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.handleResponse)
        self.nam.get(req)    
             
      
    def handleResponse(self, reply):

        er = reply.error()
        
        if er == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
    
            bytes_string = reply.readAll()
            print(str(bytes_string, 'utf-8'))
            
        else:
            print("Error occured: ", er)
            print(reply.errorString())
            
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()    
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':       
           
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you run this application, you will get the HTML code of a very simple web page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the URL example is bad. Try www.google.com. I've adapted your code for PyQt5. It works.

```
 from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
 from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
 import sys

 def printContent():
     answerAsText = bytes(replyObject.readAll()).decode("utf-8")
     print(answerAsText)


 class mainClass():
     def my_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):

         print(exctype, value, traceback)

         sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
         sys.exit(1)

     sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)

     url = QUrl("http://www.google.com")

     request = QNetworkRequest()
     request.setUrl(url)
     manager = QNetworkAccessManager()

     replyObject = manager.get(request)
     replyObject.finished.connect(printContent)

     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```